# dataTables temporarily disable sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a sortable dataTable filled with data where you can edit the data when you click on it.

Before clicking it looks like this:

```
<input type='text' value='...' size=3 disabled>
```

And when clicking:

```
$('#table1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
{
    var olddata = "";
    olddata = table.cell( this, 3 ).data();
    table.cell( this, 3 ).data( "<input type='text' value='" + olddata + "' size=3 style='background-color:white'>" );
});
```

However when you click on a row it changes position since it now also contains extra html code , and if this was the active ordering column it ends up at the bottom or top.

I sort using:

```
var columnSet = 
[
    ...
    {title: "Mycolumn", width:"1%", "type": "string"},
    ...
];
```

So my question is, is it possible to temporarily disable sorting in the whole table when a row is clicked, and then enable again when done editing, or alternatively sort based on  value attribute?

Comment: For datatable, you need to mention whether a particular column should be sortable or not. You can set all the columns to false in case you dont want sorting for any columns. The property name is "aoColumns".

Comment: Yes but i want to be able to sort them, just not when the user clicks to edit a row.

Comment: Its difficult to change the sorting the behavior of the datatable as you will have to reinitialize the datatable. Suggestion would be not to do inline edit and redirect the user to different page or use a bootstrap modal to edit the row if you are using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve this using a small trick

```
var columnSet = 
[
    ...
    {title: "Mycolumn", width:"1%", "type": "html"},
    ...
];
```

using type: html removes everything between "<" and ">" however this left me with dataTables trying to sort an empty cell since

```
<input value="...">
```

only has content between "<" and ">"

I solved this using:

```
olddata = $(table.cell( row, 5 ).data()).attr("value");
table.cell( row, 5 ).data( "<input type='text' value='" + olddata + "' size=25 style='background-color:white'><p hidden>" + olddata + "</p>" );
```

The p element will not be seen but datatable can see it and use it for sorting so the row does not change position! This solution was even better than disabling sorting since you can now still sort the table